# what is best Jboss tools or product to develop web application?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-developer-studio, jboss-web

I want to use jboss BPM to develop web  projects.
I try install devstudio-10.4.0.GA-installer-eap.jar and then add (JBOSS Business Process and Rules Development).
is that enough?
is that correct?
what is the correct scenario and best jboss tools?
thank you for your helping.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways how to develop BPMN2 process

- using Eclipse tooling (such as the Devstudio you mentioned)
- using web tooling which is delivered with jBPM installer

There is a nice documentation about how to install jbpm and how to use both toolings at
https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/6.5.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#jBPMInstaller